# Ruby support for DynamoDB

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb

Currently I'm investigation different nosql solutions to use in couple microservices. And while reading DynamoDB docs and checking aws-ruby-skd, I found out that it supports DynamoDB under API version 2012-08-10. And this's kinda far far away from 2015. 
So here's my question: Does outdated sdk support for dynamo cause any problems? Is there any sense to start use DynamoDB with ruby?

It would be great to hear someone who uses it in a big project under heavy load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API version 2012-08-10 is the latest version for DynamoDB.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DocumentHistory.html

It's more like a major version number that indicates backwards-compatibility.

The AWS Ruby SDK is also [updated regularly](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Ruby) and is kept up-to-date with the DynamoDB API (the latest DynamoDB API feature, DynamoDB Streams, was added in [AWS Ruby SDK v2.1.5](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Ruby/6267924682800223))